# pause function and resume later without corutine

Tags: lua

I am trying to implement multitasking to lua, so that I can use multiple Threads on the Node MCU.

My idea was to run the threads as functions, pause them and continue with the next and do that in a loop. The debug.sethook function seemed prommising but didn't work with the corutines, they executed the hook only after the corutine finished.
I only really need a way to pause a functon.

```
mt = {}
mt.threadList = {}

function mt.newThread(fnc)
    table.insert(mt.threadList,fnc)
end

function mt.update()
    for i=1,#mt.threadList do
        print("EPOCH: "..i)
        debug.sethook(print,"c",40)
        coroutine.resume( mt.threadList[i] )
        debug.sethook()
    end
end

function tA()
    for i=1,100 do
        print("A",i)
    end
end

function tB()
    for i=1,100 do
      print("B",i)
    end
end

mt.newThread(tA)
mt.newThread(tB)

mt.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coroutine.resume` continues a *coroutine*, not a regular function. Coroutines (from the Lua side) are generated by `coroutine.create`. `coroutine.resume` can only be called on the value returned by `coroutine.create`.

That being said, Lua coroutines are cooperative (hence the term "co-routine"). That means that you're not supposed to be able to arbitrarily interrupt their execution at any particular point. The coroutine *itself* should decide when to suspend, via a call to `coroutine.yield` or similar functions.

You can use `debug.sethook` on a coroutine to set its debug hook (if you don't pass a coroutine to `sethook`, then it assumes that you're setting the debug hook for the *current* thread, which is not what you want), and thereby `coroutine.yield` at arbitrary points in time. But you *really* shouldn't.

In any case, without coroutines, there is no way to "pause" a function's execution at all. Not even with a debug hook.